# Texlive 2020 on MacOS Catalina

Tags: texlive, mactex

I am currently running Catalina 10.15.4 and formatted my hard dive and reinstalled the operating system. As such, I needed to reinstall Latex and I installed the latest version of Mactex 2020 and then followed the instructions to install Texlive 2020 here: https://www.tug.org/mactex/mactex-unix-download.html. This installed successfully, but I cannot see an application in /Applications/TeX.

I have two questions:

1. Is there a GUI application like Texlive 2019 that can be used to
   maintain packages?
2. If not, how do you update and maintain packages using Texlive 2020?

Comment: I also have MacOS 10.15.4 "Catalina" on my system. I would recommend that you download and install MacTeX2020 by clicking on "MacTeX.pkg" at https://www.tug.org/mactex/mactex-download.html. MacTeX *is* TeXLive -- but already optimized for MacOS.

Comment: You should NOT use the “Unix download” version, which is for older versions of macOS, but the regular one (MacTeX download). For questions related to application signatures, TeX Live Utility cannot be installed by MacTeX on Catalina, you can download it from the developer's site https://amaxwell.github.io/tlutility/

Comment: @Mico - I installed the latest version of MacTex2020 from the site you mentioned. It didn't install Texlive and hence my question.

Comment: @egreg Your solution works, I installed it from the developers site.

Comment: Just to clarify what seems to be some confusion: TeX Live Utility is a GUI application for managing your distribution. TeXLive (MacTeX) is the whole distribution; it is not a GUI program.

Comment: @egreg : actually the Unix Download would get the correct binaries for Catalina but the install takes forever and you need to download another small package to install the ‘standard’ data structure used with MacTeX. @AveshenPillay : the TeX Live installed by MacTeX is in a directory that is hidden by the Finder. In Terminal try `which pdflatex` and it should be found.

Comment: Ideally MacTeX would be distributed through the Apple App Store, but they are charging 99$/year for that and you can't really expect someone who is maintaining MacTeX *for free* to pay that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I guess I have almost the same situation as yours (recently reinstalled mac os, hence the newest version Catalina 10.15.4)

As @Mico and @egreg said, since you are "Mac OS 10.13, High Sierra, or higher", you should choose [Downloading MacTeX 2020](http://www.tug.org/mactex/mactex-download.html). After downloading, open Application/Tex you will see "MISSING APPS.pdf" where they explained due to the higher security requirement from Apple, there's some notorized issues. (More details [here](https://tug.org/tug2019/preprints/koch-harden.pdf).)

Then, I just followed @egreg suggestion, download texlive from the developer's [site](http://amaxwell.github.io/tlutility)

After installing texlive, it will say "“TeX Live Utility” can’t be opened because Apple cannot check it for malicious software." whenever you want to open it. The solution is: open with "right click with the pop up {open} choices".

Thank for you raising this questions. Hope that works for you!

Edit: Even if I successfully installed and even updated TexLive apps. The next time, I cannot find this apps in my application list. Instead, I need to search it with the upper right magnifier icon and opened the same way as mentioned above (right click).

Edit 2020/6/1 on Catalina 15.5.5: When I installed MacTex, it says "This package is fully notarized, as required by the Catalina version of macOS. Some GUI applications like TeX Live Utility and BibDesk are missing because they have not been updated for notarization. To obtain them, read MISSING APPS in /Applications/TeX."

Comment: In my case it says that BibDesk, Tex Live, and cocoAspell with links to download them. Howevr, BibDesk was updated on launch, and Tex Live was already installed with the `MacTex 2020`, and on the latest version.